# How can I allow multiple petition signatures from the same computer?

Tags: joomla, civipetiton

I have a petition in CiviCRM - Joomla that is working great.  We use it as a 'Contact Us' form.  If different people want to use the same public computer to submit the form, they will get a 'duplicate' error.  How can I allow multiple people to submit comments on the same computer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you clear the browser's history after each entry you should be able to have multiple entries from the same computer.

Answer (score 1):

You can open a new private window and sign it.